# Why does mapping state to props give undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

I'm having a problem with my setup of Redux. I didn't have a problem with single file of `posts` actions and reducers, but as soon as added a `searchQueries` sections, it shows only `undefined` values for the `searchQueries` props.

I've tried copying it as far as I can and modifying it for the second set of actions/reducers, but I'm still ending up with `undefined` props in the case of `searchQueries`. I'm getting all the props, including the default values in the case of `posts`. Here's the code for each of these:

/actions/posts.js:

```
import axios from 'axios'

export function postsHasErrored(bool) {
  return {
    type: 'POSTS_HAS_ERRORED',
    hasErrored: bool
  }
}

export function postsIsLoading(bool) {
  return {
    type: 'POSTS_IS_LOADING',
    isLoading: bool
  }
}

export function postsFetchDataSuccess(posts) {
  return {
    type: 'POSTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
    posts
  }
}

export function totalPagesFetchDataSuccess(totalPages) {
  return {
    type: 'TOTAL_PAGES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS',
    totalPages
  }
}

export function postsFetchData(url) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(postsIsLoading(true))

    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200) throw Error(res.statusText)
        dispatch(postsIsLoading(false))
        return res
      })
      .then(res => {
        dispatch(postsFetchDataSuccess(res.data))
        dispatch(totalPagesFetchDataSuccess(res.headers['x-wp-totalpages']))
      })
      .catch(() => dispatch(postsHasErrored(true)))
  }
}
```

/actions/searchQueries.js:

```
const readLocation = (name) => {
    let parameter = getParameterByName(name);
    if (name === 'categories') {
      if (parameter) {
        parameter = parameter.split(',')
        for (let i = 0; i < parameter.length; i++) parameter[i] = parseInt(parameter[i], 10)
      }
      else parameter = []
    }

    if (parameter === null) {
      if (name === 'search') parameter = ''
      if (name === 'page') parameter = 1
    }

    console.log(parameter)

    return parameter
  }

export function setSearchString(searchString) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_SEARCH_STRING',
    searchString
  }
}

export function setSearchCategories(searchCategories) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_SEARCH_CATEGORIES',
    searchCategories
  }
}

export function setSearchPage(searchPage) {
  return {
    type: 'SET_SEARCH_PAGE',
    searchPage
  }
}

export function searchQueriesSetting() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setSearchString(readLocation('search')))
    dispatch(setSearchCategories(readLocation('categories')))
    dispatch(setSearchPage(readLocation('page')))
  }
}
```

/reducers/posts.js:

```
export function postsHasErrored(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POSTS_HAS_ERRORED':
      return action.hasErrored

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function postsIsLoading(state = false, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POSTS_IS_LOADING':
      return action.isLoading

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function posts(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'POSTS_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
      return action.posts

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function totalPages(state = 1, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'TOTAL_PAGES_FETCH_DATA_SUCCESS':
      return parseInt(action.totalPages, 10)

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

/reducers/searchQueries.js:

```
export function searchString(state = '', action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_STRING':
      return action.searchString

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function searchCategories(state = [], action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_CATEGORIES':
      return action.searchCategories

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function searchPage(state = 1, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_PAGE':
      return action.searchPage

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

/reducers/index.js:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { posts, totalPages, postsHasErrored, postsIsLoading } from './posts'
import { searchString, searchCategories, searchPage } from './searchQueries'

export default combineReducers({
  posts,
  postsHasErrored,
  postsIsLoading,
  totalPages,

  searchString,
  searchCategories,
  searchPage
})
```

/components/PostsList.js

```
// dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// components
import PostsListItem from './PostsListItem'
import PostsPages from './PostsPages'
// actions
import { postsFetchData } from '../actions/posts'
import { searchQueriesSetting } from '../actions/searchQueries'
// styles
import '../styles/css/postsList.css'
// shared modules
import { createSearchUrl } from '../sharedModules/sharedModules'

class PostsList extends Component {

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.searchPage !== this.props.searchPage) this.componentDidMount()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.searchQueriesSetting()
    this.props.fetchData(createSearchUrl(
      'http://localhost/wordpress-api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=1',
      this.props.searchCategories,
      this.props.searchString,
      this.props.searchPage
    ))
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    const { isLoading, hasErrored, posts } = this.props
    if (isLoading) return <div className='posts-list'><h2 className='loading'>Loading...</h2></div>

    const postsList = posts.map(post => <PostsListItem post={post} key={post.id} />)

    return (
      <div className='posts-list'>
        {postsList}
        <PostsPages />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    posts: state.posts,
    hasErrored: state.postsHasErrored,
    isLoading: state.postsIsLoading,
    searchCategories: state.searchCategories,
    searchString: state.searchString,
    searchPage: state.searchPage
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchData: (url) => dispatch(postsFetchData(url)),
    searchQueriesSetting: () => dispatch(searchQueriesSetting())
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsList)
```

/components/PostsPages.js

```
// dependencies
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
// actions
import { setSearchPage } from '../actions/searchQueries'
// shared modules
import { createSearchUrl } from '../sharedModules/sharedModules'

class PostsPages extends Component {
  isLinkEdgy = (pageNumber) => {
    if (parseInt(pageNumber, 10) <= 1) return ''
    if (parseInt(pageNumber, 10) >= parseInt(this.props.totalPages, 10)) return this.props.totalPages
    return pageNumber
  }

  render() {
    const { totalPages, currentPage, searchCategories, searchString, setSearchPage } = this.props

    const previousUrl = createSearchUrl('/blog', searchCategories, searchString, this.isLinkEdgy(parseInt(currentPage, 10) - 1))
    const nextUrl = createSearchUrl('/blog', searchCategories, searchString, this.isLinkEdgy(parseInt(currentPage, 10) + 1))

    return (
      <div className='posts-pages'>
        <ul className='posts-pages-list'>
          <li><Link to={previousUrl} onClick={() => setSearchPage(this.isLinkEdgy(parseInt(currentPage, 10) - 1))}>Prev page</Link></li>
          <li><Link to={nextUrl} onClick={() => setSearchPage(this.isLinkEdgy(parseInt(currentPage, 10) + 1))}>Next page</Link></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    totalPages: state.totalPages,
    currentPage: state.searchPage,
    searchCategories: state.searchCategories,
    searchString: state.searchString
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setSearchPage: (searchPage) => dispatch(setSearchPage(searchPage))
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PostsPages)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're accessing the wrong par of state. Take a look at your `combineReducers` call:

```
export default combineReducers({
  posts,
  postsHasErrored,
  postsIsLoading,
  totalPages,

  setSearchString,
  setSearchCategories,
  setSearchPage
})
```

Per [the Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html):

> ### `combineReducers(reducers)`
>
> **The shape of the state object matches the keys of the passed `reducers`**.

Thus your `state` object actually looks like this:

```
{
  posts: ...,
  postsHasErrored: ...,
  postsIsLoading: ...,
  totalPages: ...,
  setSearchString: ...,
  setSearchCategories: ...,
  setSearchPage: ...
}
```

In your `mapDispatchToProps`, you're trying to access the wrong part of state:

```
currentPage: state.searchPage,
searchCategories: state.searchCategories,
searchString: state.searchString
```

Since `state.searchPage` and the other two don't exist in the `state` object, *you get `undefined`*. Instead, make sure you access the keys which have the same name as the reducers:

```
currentPage: state.setSearchPage,
searchCategories: state.setSearchCategories,
searchString: state.setSearchString
```

Or just rename your reducers (which would be preferable as they are misnomers right now). Get rid of the `set` prefix on the reducers, they are not *actions*.

Comment: Thanks very much. This was so simple. Just naming. Do you know any dev tools that could have picked up the naming mismatch? And maybe some reading material in case you think I could improve a thing or two in my code?

Comment: @MateuszMysiak I don't think so. As for any other reading material, your code looks fine right now, though if you want to, review the [Redux documentation](http://redux.js.org) for tips on state managing, immutability, core principles, etc.

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to implement a PostsPages component with buttons to go to the previous or next page of posts. Would You have any idea why the state is updated, URLs and the whole PostsPages component is updated but the PostsList component isn't?

Comment: For what it's worth, the [Structuring Reducers - Using `combineReducers`](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html) section also emphasizes that this is a common mistake.