# Redux reducer with object.assign creates key inside a top key with the same name

Tags: reactjs, redux, state, immutability, spread-syntax

I'm trying to move from the simple example I've learnt on Medium about Redux to properly modify immutable state with object.assign or the spread operator. However, after I've tried this it creates a key in the original state key with the same name. F.e. I had a state key `searchPage: 1` and after converting the reducer I've got `searchPage: {searchPage: 1}`. I bet it's silly, but I did it according to the Redux docs (I only assume). I've tried object.assign and the spread operator, which have the same results. Here is my old reducer:

```
export function searchPage(state = 1, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_PAGE':
      return action.searchPage

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

and the new with spread operator:

```
export function searchPage(state = 1, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_PAGE':
      return { ...state, searchPage: action.searchPage }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

***update*** Now, I'm using an initialState object to set initial state for all reducers to an object as a default. However, the spread operator syntax now does exactly the same as before, i.e. inserts the initial state key inside the searchPage key, so I still end up with object inside my searchPage key instead of a number. Here's the updated code, I have no idea if I go in the right direction:

```
const initialState = {
  posts: [],
  postsHasErrored: false,
  postsIsLoading: false,
  searchString: '',
  searchCategories: [],
  searchPage: 10
}

export function searchString(state = initialState.searchString, action) {
  console.log(state)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_STRING':
      return action.searchString

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function searchCategories(state = initialState.searchCategories, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_CATEGORIES':
      return action.searchCategories

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function searchPage(state = initialState.searchPage, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_PAGE':
      return { ...state, searchPage: action.searchPage }

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: Your old and new reducers implement different behaviors. In first case, *all* state is simple number, so you replace it to new number. In second case, you always create new object by `Object.assign`, to which your spread operator is transpiled.

Comment: How do I get over it then? Should I leave it as is or change my initial state for the whole application? The problem I'm having is that my React app doesn't re-render after f.e. searchPage is updated in the state, so I thought it's because of the way I'm modifying state. Here's more code of my app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45256875/why-does-mapping-state-to-props-give-undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just got an update of this old issue. Now, when I look at it it's obvious. In the reducer, when initializing `state = initialState.searchPage` it should just be `state = initialState`, and the whole reducer should be just one function so that I can utilize the use case for the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your `action.searchPage` value. I think it's an object. Once go through debugging for `action` object.

try like this

```
export function searchPage(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_SEARCH_PAGE':
      return { ...state, searchPage: action.searchPage };

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: action.searchPage is always an int number.

Comment: @MateuszMysiak Are you sure for that? If so initialise your `state` with an empty object as in updated answer.

Comment: I've done that. Still the same result. In my app state there is ```searchPage: {searchPage: 1}``` instead of ```searchPage: 1```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well.
By researching online I've seen people saying you just needed to initialize your state empty in actions, and while that helped me while I was using only one item from state, it went downhill when I needed two.

This new error happened at my own component file, at `mapStateToProps`. 
Because this works...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => (
   state.posts
);
```

But this doesn't...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => (
   state.posts, state.comments
);
```

So I'd end up writing...

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
   posts: state.posts,
   comments: state.comments
});
```

Which would duplicate the key name, causing the arrays to be posts.posts and comments.comments. After trying many different syntaxes, I finally found what works:

```
function mapStateToProps(state){
  const { posts } = state.posts
  const { comments } = state.comments
  return { posts, comments}
}
```

Hope it helps someone!